# insert values only if subselect is not null

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to write sql that will create a new table using data from an existing table. 
The new table will have, among other columns, two columns like so:

```
reserved  boolean
reserved_for character varying(10)
```

In the **original** table, I have data that looks like this:

```
     id      | identification |             department             |                description                |     lastchange      | available |  type  
------------+----------------+------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+---------------------+-----------+--------
 9145090050 |                |                                    | Reserved for llb                          | 2011-05-20 11:46:21 | f         | 
 9145090096 |                |                                    | Reserved for ppa                          | 2013-01-26 12:31:56 | f         | 
 9145090046 |                |                                    |                                         | 2011-05-06 10:34:21 | f         |
```

If the original table has the text "Reserved for ..." then, I want the reserved field in the new table to be set to "true" and reserved_for to contain the 3 or 4 characters that follow the "Reserved for" text in the original table.
So using the above table as an example, I want my **new table** to look like this;

```
     id     | reserved |  reserved_for  |  lastchange         |  
------------+----------+----------------+---------------------+
 9145090050 | true     | llb            | 2011-05-20 11:46:21 |  
 9145090096 | true     | ppa            | 2013-01-26 12:31:56 | 
 9145090046 | false    |                | 2011-05-06 10:34:21 |
```

The query I have to extract the 4 characters after the "Reserved for " looks like this:

```
   select 
      substring(description from 13 for 4) 
   from
      definition 
   where 
      description like 'Reserved for%';
```

It works in that it extracts the characters I need. How do I write the conditional statement in my create table command?

Comment: Note: Maybe you should learn about 1NF https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form

Comment: Thanks.  But i already understand the principle of normalizing data... which is why I'm trying to get data out of a poorly designed db into something cleaner @wildplasser

Comment: Note: you don't need the `reserved` column in the new table. It has the same meaning as a NOT NULL value on the `reserved_for` column.

Comment: @wildplasser thanks.  I'm actually refactoring for mongodb so we'll see how it behaves / works.  thanks for taking the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is just some string manipulation on the original table:

```
select id,
       (description like 'Reserved for%') as Reserved,
       (case when description like 'Reserved for%'
             then substring(description from 14) 
        end) as Reserved_For,
       last_change
from original;
```

Comment: cool.  i think you just need to change the column "reserved_for" to description in some spots... but other than that, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will help..

```
insert into yourtable(id,reserved,reserved_for,lastchange)
select t1.id, 
       case when t1.description like 'Reserved for%' then true else false end as reserved,
       case when when t1.description like 'Reserved for%' then substr('reserved for llb',strpos('reserved for llb','for') + 4) else null end as reserved_for,
       lastchange
from table t1
```

Comment: or you can just replace the strpos function with 14, if you would like